# GET Value Inside Of Span Class

Tags: php, class, get

I am having trouble getting the GET value to go in place of what I have labeled (TEST). What format is needed for this type of code?

```
<span class="example" data-example-username="(TEST)"></span>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: <span class="example" data-example-username="' . $_GET['u'] . '"></span>

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<span class="example" data-example-username="<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>"></span>
```

Comment: Great! Worked! I tried something similar to that, however I left out the echo part.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

```
# Check to see if the GET param is set at all
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
    $user = $_GET['username']; # Assign the value
} else {
    $user = 'no-user-specified';
}

# Echo your span
echo "<span ... data-example-username='$user'></span>";
```

And what you shouldn't do...

```
echo "<span ... data-example-username='{GET['user']}></span>";
```

This approach has a number of problems.  Firstly, it is assumed here you aren't sanitizing the value at all or checking its validity.  Secondly it will throw an error if you assume it is set when it is not (hence the call to `isset()`).

Finally, if you do not want the entire string in PHP and just want to echo the variable, you can do like this:

```
<span ... field="<?php echo $value; ?>"></span>
```

Or

```
<span ... field="<?php echo $GET['email']; ?>"></span>
```

(which, again, you shouldn't do :-)